# Use checkbox to show/hide multiple input fields with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, show-hide

How can I show each input after the checkbox with Jquery hide/show for multiple fields?

The HTML is correct and if the second function is removed from the JS code this will work (**see [demo on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q5v18o58/1/)**) with the first checkbox and input... but, I don't know how to write the Jquery code for multiple fields for this HTML structure.

Is there a way to make it work correctly with less JS code, like in a single function and keep it easy for adding multiple fields (#3, #4, ... N)

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="trigger" name="showhidecheckbox">show/hide input #1
  <div id="showthis">
    <input type="text" id="hidden_field" name="showhideinput">
  </div>
  <br>

  <input type="checkbox" id="trigger2" name="showhidecheckbox2">show/hide input #2
  <div id="showthis2">
    <input type="text" id="hidden_field" name="showhideinput2">
  </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {

  // Set vars
  var checkbox = $("#trigger");
  var hidden = $("#showthis");

  // Hide fields
  hidden.hide();

  // checkbox event listener
  checkbox.change(function() {
    // See if checked, show/hide
    if (checkbox.is(':checked')) {
      hidden.show();
    } else {
      hidden.hide();
    }
  });
});

$(function() {

  // Set vars
  var checkbox = $("#trigger2);
  var hidden= $("#showthis2);

  // Hide fields
  hidden.hide();

  // checkbox event listener
  checkbox.change(function() {
    // See if checked, show/hide
    if (checkbox.is(':checked')) {
      hidden.show();
    } else {
      hidden.hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you can use a combination of common classes to group elements and event handlers. Within those event handlers you can use the `this` keyword to reference the clicked element and traverse the DOM to find the related elements.

Once you've found the related `.showthis` div you can use `toggle()` to hide or show it based on the checked state of the checkbox. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.trigger').change(function() {
    $(this).next('.showthis').toggle(this.checked);
  })
});
```

```css
.showthis {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post">
  <input type="checkbox" class="trigger" name="showhidecheckbox">show/hide input #1
  <div class="showthis">
    <input type="text" name="showhideinput">
  </div><br>

  <input type="checkbox" class="trigger" name="showhidecheckbox2">show/hide input #2
  <div class="showthis">
    <input type="text" name="showhideinput2">
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
  $(this).next().find('input').toggle()
})
```

It says when you change the checkbox, look in the next div, find the input and toggle the visibility:

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
  $(this).next().find('input').toggle()
})
```

```css
input[type="text"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post">
  <input type="checkbox" id="trigger" name="showhidecheckbox">show/hide input #1
  <div id="showthis">
    <input type="text" id="hidden_field1" name="showhideinput">
  </div>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="trigger2" name="showhidecheckbox2">show/hide input #2
  <div id="showthis2">
    <input type="text" id="hidden_field2" name="showhideinput2">
  </div>
</form>
```